# Increase number by one on different sheet without selecting sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that increase a cell by 1 on the active sheet but I need to change the code to increase a number on a different sheet without selecting the sheet that I want to increase the number on

Example: I have 5 sheets that are the same and run the same macro and the 6th sheet I have has a invoice number that I need to increase by 1 without selecting it

Here's the code I'm using now

```
Range("X1").Value = Range("X1").Value + 1
```

I've tried

```
Sheets("sheet6").Range("O2").Value = Range("O2").Value + 1
```

but it just make the cell value 1

Comment: If the cell has nothing or zero, it will put 1 in the cell. If the cell has a number, it will put the number + 1. If the cell has a text, it will bring an error.

Comment: Beware that typing `Range("O2")` will take the range from the sheet where **the code is**. It's not necessarily "sheet 6". Use `Sheets("sheet6")` on both sides of the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell has nothing or zero, it will put 1 in the cell. If the cell has a number, it will put the number + 1. If the cell has a text, it will bring an error.

Beware that typing `Range("O2")` will take the range from the sheet where **the code is**. It's not necessarily "sheet 6". (So if in that sheet the value is empty, it will result in 1)

Use Sheets("sheet6") on both sides of the assignment.

```
Sheets("sheet6").Range("O2").Value = Sheets("sheet6").Range("O2").Value + 1
```